# Android - java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid double: "0,64"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to do some basic math here, but I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.welldana.christian.welldanaapp/com.welldana.christian.welldanaapp.GUI.ResultActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "0,64"
```

**Code doing the math:**

```
public double CalculateFilterAreaRequirement(){
    CalculateTurnoverPerHour();
    double tmp = turnoverPerHour/turnoverRate;
    filterAreaRequirement = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(tmp));
    return filterAreaRequirement;
}
```

I don't know why it's replacing `.` with `,`

Comment: What localisation is your device set to? A lot of european languages will expect `,` instead of `.` for the decimal separator

Comment: Denmark, but how do I tell it to use `.` instead of `,`?

Answer (score 2):

`DecimalFormat` uses the decimal formatting appropriate for your `Locale` while `Double.parseDouble()` doesn't. Your default locale has `,` as decimal separator.

You *could* specify an explicit locale to use but formatting and parsing back a value doesn't make much sense. If you need to truncate to two decimals, just use

```
Math.floor(tmp * 100) / 100
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Worked as intended. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`DecimalFormat` is `Locale` sensitive. And probably your Locale uses `,` as decimal separator. Try forcing a Locale that uses . for it, E.g. `Locale.US`